# extra dot after month in iOS10 swift

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10

I am using following code to get date and store it in String ()

```
let date = self.getDateFromStringWithFormatted(self.startDate, format: "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

for iOS9
it shows date like = `"30-Dec-16"`
and
For iOS10 
it shows date like = `"30-Dec.-2016"`

for iOS10 it shows extra `.` after the month `Dec`

Can anyone please help me why this is so.
I need either of one 
`.` in iOS9 or remove `.` in iSO10

Thanks in advance.

Here is screen shot.

iOS9

[image]

iOS10

[image]

Comment: `MM` does not return the three letter abbreviation of the month. The error might occur somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Local Identifier

`let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")`
// IF Format is "dd MMM yyyy" Or "dd MMM"

It Should Display "21 Dec 2016" or  "21 Dec"

[For More reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `"dd-MM-yyyy"` format will not produce three letter abbreviation. Maybe you use `"dd-MMM-yyyy"` format. In this case nobody says there will be exactly three letters without dots in all languages. If you want to display 20-Dec-16 on every machine, set locale to `en_US_POSIX`.